# Looking for something like the gnome2 weather clock for KDE

Tags: fedora, kde, plasma

I work with people from multiple timezones and I loved how I could have several displayed under my main time in gnome2 (I was using scientific linux). I happen to have a screenshot of it as you can see below.

[image: KDE4 time panel]

However on Fedora 22 (KDE 5.12) the timezone panel sucks. It doesn't even show when one time is for a different date.

[image: KDE5 time panel]

How could I go about getting something like the first picture on KDE? Or at least something better than what is there now.

Comment: Anyone? *voice echoes around empty room*

Answer (score 1):

There is no KDE Plasma 5.12. Judging by the screenshot, you're referring to KDE Plasma 5.3 or older.

In the upcoming KDE Plasma 5.4 release the clock tooltip has slightly improved in terms of "timezones having a different date" as the date will now be just shown by default:

[image: clock tooltip in KDE Plasma 5.4]

I agree that having something with a visual representation of the timezones would be a nice thing to have. You could file an "Enhancement" bug at [bugs.kde.org](http://bugs.kde.org) and/or discuss this idea with the devs in #plasma (Freenode).

Comment: Ah, I was going off of

`$ konsole --version\\
Qt: 5.4.2\\
KDE Frameworks: 5.12.0\\
Konsole: 15.04.0`

But here I see the 5.3 number.

`$ dnf list plasma-desktop*\\
Installed Packages\\
plasma-desktop.x86_64                      5.3.2-3.fc22`

Comment: *KDE* is the community developing all the libraries and software, *KDE Frameworks* are libraries used by *KDE Applications* and *KDE Plasma*, *KDE Plasma* is the desktop shell, *KDE Applications* are applications completing the desktop environment.

Comment: @EliasProbst I'm running Plasma 5.4 now (in Arch Linux), but mine looks [slightly different](http://i.imgur.com/VU3Wnbg.png). Some are probably just differences in locale, but mine is full of acronyms that I don't understand. Does yours still have acronyms or names of cities?

Comment: This is [configurable](http://i.imgur.com/YeO48g8.png).